# Cascade Dropdown and set Detail value properly

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have the following cascade relationships between `Parent` and `Child` categories and keep the `ChildCategoryId` in the `Personel` table. When creating a new `Personel` record there are 2 cascade `Dropdownlist` and child records are listed according to their parents. Only `ChildCategoryId` is saved to the `Personel` table e.g. when select `Education` and `Sales`, the `ChildCategoryId` is 3. However, when selecting a parent record that has no child i.e. `Family` or `Culture`, I have no idea what value should be saved to the `Personel` table.

Of course I can add two *"N/A"* records to the `Child` table for `Family` or `Culture` records and save their `Id`s to the `Personel` table, but I am not sure if it is a good idea. Because when I list the `Child` category name, *"N/A"* will be displayed on the details page.

Is there a best practices for this kind of scenarios?

***Personel:***

```
Id   |  Name  |  ChildCategoryId |
----------------------------------
1001 |  John  |  1               |
1002 |  Mary  |  2               |
1003 |  Bill  |  3               |
1004 |  Jose  |  4               |
1005 |  Anna  |  5               |
```

***ChildCategory:***

```
Id  |  Name    |  ParentCategoryId |
-----------------------------------
1   |  IT      |  101              |
2   |  Finance |  102              |
3   |  Sales   |  102              |
4   |  PR      |  103              |
5   |  HR      |  103              |
```

***ParentCategory:***

```
Id  |  Name      | 
------------------
101 |  Health    |
102 |  Education |
103 |  Sport     |
104 |  Family    |
105 |  Culture   |
```

Comment: If I understand this correctly, if someone selects 104-Family, the child list will not populate with anything because there is not related item in the child list. So child and Personnel would just be null.

Comment: @BattlFrog Yes, it can be set as null. BUT in this case how can I go to Parent of this Child? As I said, I must use child record in the Personel table and go to Parent table from this child via Foreign Key. So, what should I do in this case? I think null is not a good idea for this scenario.

Comment: It sounds to me like a business rule question.  From what I'm seeing, there is nothing to store because there is no value.  If the user selects 104 - Family, there is no child value, so there is no value to save. It is null. So either the business needs to add related values to the child table for parent 104 & 105 so the child value can be saved, or the business needs to tell you what they want to see if there is no child value.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but I used to save both Parent and Child Category in the Personel table in one of the previous projects. But I think there is no need to keep both Foreign Keys in the Personel table and I can navigate to the ParentCategory using ChildCategory. For this reason I wanted to build a structure using this approach but very confused. So, what is your suggestion regarding to this issue?

Comment: Any help please???

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding your question, I cant give you my opinion on your business rules.  If you have a question about how to code it, let me know.

Comment: No, I do not need help at code level, instead I need your suggestion on business rule that fix the problem properly. I think you can give your opinion that let me help much. It is normal to post suggestions as best practices here and I think you have idea about that :)

Comment: You've got [java] and [entity-framework] as tags. Are you really using entity framework?

Comment: @GertArnold What if I use Entity Framework or Java? Would you help me? If so, yes I use Entity Framework and I think the approach regarding to the solution of this question is the same for EF, MSSQL, C# and also other similar languages and frameworks that faces the same issue e.g. MySQL. Now I hope you have also some fix in order to post besides question for a question.

Comment: I removed the [java] tag because it's irrelevant. In fact, the other tags are irrelevant as well, because this is a general business problem.

Comment: The only problem you state is "when I list the Child category name, "N/A" will be displayed on the details page." So what else do you want to display if no child category is selected? I don't understand why not selecting a child category and a nullable `ChildCategoryId` column is a problem.

Comment: Because I will use ChildCategoryId in order to navigate ParentCategory table. If I use null for ChildCategoryId then I need to ad an extra column (ParentCategoryId) to the Personel table. Maybe it is not so bad to ad an extra and use both ParentId and ChildId columns in the Personel table. BUT I think it would be better to use only one FK Id that can also be user to navigate to its parent Id. Would not it?

Comment: If I understand this correctly some categories don't have (and won't ever have) child categories. The selected category is always "a category". In that case you should have one hierarchical Category table in which a nullable `ParentId` refers to its own primary key. That way you can always select (and store) one category and the level in the hierarchy won't matter.